# virtual monitor when using Nvidia graphics for VNC based second monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, vnc

I am trying to use my iPad (or any tablet) as a second portable monitor with my laptop using a VNC client on my iPad and VNC server showing the second dummy/virtual monitor from laptop.

There are scripts to do this using `xrandr` like [VirtScreen](https://github.com/kbumsik/VirtScreen), [this python script](https://github.com/mrenrich84/vnc_virtual_display_linker). I have found many such scripts while searching. Basically they use `xrandr` to create a `VIRTUAL` screen with a resolution, place it to the right/left of primary laptop display, and make `x11vnc` send this `VIRTUAL` screen to VNC client.

Problem occurs when creating virtual screen `VIRTUAL1` when using Nvidia graphics card. Apparently this is not possible.
A solution to this problem is (from [here](https://github.com/mrenrich84/vnc_virtual_display_linker/issues/4#issuecomment-447587604)) creating a new file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` containing:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "intelgpu0"
Driver "intel"
Option "VirtualHeads" "2"
EndSection
```

Creating this file will add two virtual screens in `xrandr` listing and the scripts work good. But when this file is present Nvidia graphics is not used, instead intel's integrated graphics is used. I have written a script which will create or delete this `20-intel.conf` file when ever I want to use the second display.

I really don't like using integrated graphics entirely when I want to use this second screen. Is there any other way where I can do this only with Nvidia graphics, or use Nvidia from primary and integrated for second display ?

I am using Pop_OS (which has separate ISO file for specifically for Nvidia graphics). Is this a problem with Pop_OS or Nvidia graphics in general or any graphics? I have tried replacing `VIRTUAL1` in those scripts with `HDMI-1-1` and tried adding the line `Option "VirtualHeads" "2"` in pre-existing `10-nvidia.conf` file, but no use.

Comment: I think NVIDIA has a guide for that. https://docs.nvidia.com/grid/9.0/grid-vgpu-user-guide/index.html#installing-configuring-x11vnc-on-linux-server

Comment: Sorry for a really late reply.. I glanced through it. It describes how to connect for servers not laptop. Nonetheless, I did not find how to create a second display. I already have one, I want a second one. There is a command `cat /proc/*/environ 2>/dev/null | tr '\0' '\n' | grep '^DISPLAY=:' | uniq` mentioned which only prints displays already present. Guess I will have to tinker with screen section in xorg.conf file. I don't have experience with it, but will try sometime. The section did not describe how to create a second display explicitly.